# Is it possible to hide the navigation bar from XML-file of activity's layout?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, navigationbar

I have a simple app with just one activity. I'm trying to hide the navigation bar from the landscape version of the main activity's layout file.

I tried to find the specific attribute in AppCompat theme and create a custom style that would hide the bar from my layout but haven't found anything matching my goal. I know that it can be done in my activity's class code but I wonder if this is possible to set up in the layout file.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

No way, you can hide navigation bar from swipe gesture in setting device.